# Coordinate scale different (much smaller) than map

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, coordinates

I've set up a new project with the CRS set to WGS84 (EPSG:4326). Then I added a google map and a CVS with my Lat/Lon coordinates in degrees. there is nothing else in the CSV other than the header. At a zoomed out view, my points all show up as a single point around the west coast of Africa near (0,0). Please see the first map. When I zoom way in, they are revealed to have the right configuration. Please see the second map. I've included a screenshot from when I add the delimited text layer (numbers after decimal have been crossed out in red for privacy).

How do I fix this?? I know this is something simple..

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: The top map is **not** in 4326, but 3857 (Web Mercator). You're mapping degrees as meters  on "Null Island".

Comment: It seems like you changed the CRS of the Google Maps layer.

Comment: Thank you Vince and Gabriel De Luca!! Here is the correct configuration: Project CRS = EPSG:3857 - WGS 84 Pseudo-Mercator; map CRS =  EPSG:3857 - WGS 84 Pseudo-Mercator; coordinate CSV CRS = EPSG:4326 - WGS 84

Answer (score 1):

Your screenshots show a map rendered in EPSG:4326 (bottom right), which is geographic coordinates (latitude, longitude). The coordinates of the cursor are also read in the status bar, with numbers in the order of 4 million and 2 million.

So, based on your screenshots, the base layer is being rendered on a world that is at least 4 million degrees wide, so it follows that the system for that layer (base map) is not correct (must be EPSG:3857, but seems to be EPSG:4326).

In my opinion the points are well placed. I sense that you could have changed the system of the base layer. So the solution will be to change it back to the system that corresponds to it.

The project or map can be rendered on any system.